# Unable to create pg_stat_statements view in Postgresql 9.4

Tags: sql, windows, restart, event-log, postgresql-9.4

I'm unable to create `pg_stat_statements` view in Postgresql 9.4 on Windows Server.

I want to view this table so as to get the top running queries on my Postgresql database.

For this I enabled:
`shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'`
in my Postgresql.conf file. As this update requires a restart, as soon as I restarted my postgresql service on Windows, I got an unable to restart error.

I can see this particular message in my event log viewer:

> "FATAL:  could not access file "pg_stat_statements": No such file or directory"

How can I create the `pg_stat_statements` view?

Comment: Check that it is actually installed.

Comment: I can see pg_stat_statements view under public schemas. Though when I try to to select * from pg_stat_statements, i get an error "
ERROR: pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
SQL state: 55000" . Please note my shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements' in posgresql.conf is still commented as it gives the error while restarting service.

Comment: Check that it is actually installed on the file system, that is.